# Transitioning from java to C++

Tags: java, c++, file, transition

Based both on when the languages were invented and the structure of the languages, this transition is probably meant to go the other way, but I am fairly confident in my java abilities, or at least I am good enough at it.. but I am trying to now go to C++, and I am having difficulties.

In java, reading a text file could be done by declaring a new file object, and then a scanner, (or some like class) to read it, or the reader classes, (buffered reader,  input stream reader, file reader... the list of variations continues)  But now I am trying to do that in C++, a very basic function of a program, and my code is not working.  The code I have is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "This text appears in the file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

what am I forgetting?  It seems complete to me, but then again, I know hardly any C++...

Comment: First, you shouldn't try to convert your Java knowledge to C++. You'll only massively confuse yourself and produce very very poor code. You should start from the absolute ground up with a good intro C++ book.

Comment: This code works fine on my platform (Linux/g++). Note that the `open` is not necessary because you can construct an `ofstream` from a filename, and `close` is not necessary because the destructor will close the file.

Comment: In addition to what Falmarri said, the only way your java knowledge is helpful is by seeing problems solved in both languages - and then comparing them, both for similarities and differences.

Comment: You don;t need to explicitly call open() or close(). RAII will take care of that for you. Only use these methods if there is a possibility of something going wrong that you want to catch **and** do something about.

Answer (score 4):

That code is correct.  Are you sure the example.txt file isn't being created?  For example, if you are using visual studio then it won't be in the Debug or Release folders but will show up one level up since that is what the working directory will be by default.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your real question is how to learn C++ when already familiar with Java. For this I would recommend the book [Accelarated C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X). It's a very good introduction to C++. However, it is dense and will require some study. It took me about two months to work though it.

If you don't have the time or motivation for that you could start with [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889). It's basically a collection of do's and don'ts that will help you avoid the common beginner mistakes.

Answer (score -3):

Java baggage is a liability, not an asset. Thinking in C++ you would make this code both simpler and safer:

```
#include <fstream>

int main () {
  std::ofstream myfile("example.txt");
  myfile << "This text appears in the file.\n";
  return 0; // you can skip this too
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
#include <fstream>

int main () { std::ofstream("example.txt") << "This text appears in the file.\n";}
```

Comment: The second example doesn't work. It produces a file containing a string representation of an address (like "0x100000dd8").

Comment: @StackedCrooked, you right! This is an interesting example, I doubt those "-" clickers actually understood. The reason you see an address printed is because basic_ostream has a member operator << (const void*) that was matched. The operator << which accepts const char* is non-member and for some unknown reason it takes l-value reference, instead of perfect forwarding they would have had with r-value reference. So, alas, r-values are not accepted with no good reason, and that's the only reason shorter example doesn't print text.

Comment: P.S. Actually, it's a defective implementation, just checked C++0x, they did it correctly, with perfect forwarding, so the r-values should work just fine:

template<class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&& os,
const basic_string<charT,traits,Allocator>& str);